# Call a View from another ViewController Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a ViewController that has a UIView set on top of it and a button that opens a popover to another ViewController. I want a button on the popover view controller to set the UIView to disable. How do I reference the UIView from the first view controller from a button in the second view controller?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Below is code that I use to call the popover view controller. Notice how I call `dimView.isHidden = false` from this first viewcontroller. I want to run `dimView.isHidden = true` from the popover view controller.

```
let popover = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverVC")

popover?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popover?.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

popover?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
popover?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)

popover?.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

dimView.isHidden = false

self.present(popover!, animated: false)
```

EDIT 2:

Below is my popover view controller. Since it is not called PopoverVC. I updated the answer to include `let popover = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverVC") as! PopOverViewController` but still no luck.

```
import UIKit


var parentController:UIViewController?

class PopOverViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)  
    }

}
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
class ViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         dimView.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var dimView: UIView!
```

Comment: Check out delegates. A good starting point could be [this article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/).

Comment: Pass a reference to the first view controller (or its view) to the second controller when you create it.

Comment: @PhillipMills what would the syntax be to create the reference?

Comment: That depends on how you create/display the second controller.

Comment: @PhillipMills Its just a second view controller that I set up in my storyboard. I added the code that I use to call the view controller as a popover to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to your current view controller when presenting your `PopoverVC` and then you can access its view from `PopoverVC`. Just create a property in `PopoverVC` that can store the reference, like `var parentController:UIViewController?`

```
let popover = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverVC") as! PopoverViewController

popover?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popover?.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

popover?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
popover?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)

popover?.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
popover?.dimView = self.dimView

dimView.isHidden = false

self.present(popover!, animated: false)
```

PopOverViewController:

```
class PopOverViewController: UIViewController {

    var dimView:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: After I create `let parentController:UIViewController?` in my popoverVC viewDidLoad how do I pass the UIview from the first controller to the parentcontroller variable?

Comment: `parentController` should actually be mutable, I have updated my answer. See my answer, this line does the trick: `popover?.parentController = self`. This way you actually pass a reference to your `ViewContoller`, not just a `UIView`, but you can access the view in `PopoverVC` as `parentController.myView` (you should change `myView` of course to whatever the name of the view you want to hide is).

Comment: If I put `popover?.parentController = self` in my code block that I attached to my question, I get the following error: `Value of type UIViewController has no member parentController`

Comment: Right, you didn't cast `popover` to `PopoverVC` when instantiating it. See my updated answer.

Comment: `Value of type PopoverVC has no member parentController` is now showing. I have `var parentController:UIViewController?`  in my popover view controller.

Comment: It seems like you haven't actually set up `parentController` as an instance property of `PopoverVC`. Please include the code of your `PopoverVC` class in your question so that I can see if you did it correctly or not.

Comment: I added my popover view controller code to original question.

Comment: As I suspected, you have not set up `parentController` properly. If you defined a variable outside a class, it will become a global variable. You need to defined all type/instance variables **inside** your class definition. See my updated answer.

Comment: That worked but I still am unable to get access to my dimView UIView from the original view controller. `self.parentController.dimView` does not exist.

Comment: That line shouldn't even compile, since `parentController` is an optional. What if you do `parentController?.dimView`? If even that doesn't help, please update your question with the latest version of your `PopoverVC` code including the line where you try to access `dimView` and the exact error.

Comment: `UIViewController has no member dimVIew` I have dimVIew defined as an outlet in my original View Controller like so: `@IBOutlet weak var dimView: UIView!`

Comment: What is the type of your view controller class that has the property `dimView`? Just change the type of `parentController` to that class and it should work.

Comment: I added my original view controller class code to original question. Its type is of `FormViewController` so I changed it to `var parentController:FormViewController?` and `parentController?.dimView?` still does not work. FormViewController has no member dimVIew.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149631/discussion-between-david-pasztor-and-martheli).